# Using Array to check for Consecutive

Tags: c++, arrays

I am building a Yahtzee game where I want the user to try and get a straight (where all 5 dice are the same value).

I have it setup to re roll the dice using the array. Like so:

```
if(userDice1 == 'n') dice[0] = rand() % 6 + 1;
if(userDice2 == 'n') dice[1] = rand() % 6 + 1;
if(userDice3 == 'n') dice[2] = rand() % 6 + 1;
if(userDice4 == 'n') dice[3] = rand() % 6 + 1;
if(userDice5 == 'n') dice[4] = rand() % 6 + 1;
```

I just need help creating the if statement to check and see if they are consecutive. I originally was going to use the sum of the dice but realized that would be buggy depending on which dice they keep.

Goal is to have like:

1 2 3 4 5
or

2 3 4 5 6

Figure there as to be another way to test if they have all consecutive numbers.

Comment: A straight is when dice have consecutive values. All dice having the same value is 5 of a kind. Which do you really mean?

Comment: `if(userDice1 == userDice2 == userDice3 == userDice4 == userDice5 )`

Comment: @AditiRawat That doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: Sorry yes I have the Yahtzee Function. So I'm doing the straight like 2 3 4 5 6 or 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @TylerK have you tried with a set?

Comment: @Carlos I have not, idk if I'm familar with that

Comment: @TylerK ok so look at my answer. A set will keep unique values. So if you add a number like 5 to a set more than once, it's still only there once. See how that's useful?

Comment: Interesting, I 'm reading up on it a little bit right now just to see how to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: @Carlos could you give a more depth answer of how I can relate it to my already existing array?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a more elegant way, but you could use a set data structure for this. If there are any duplicates your set will not have 5 entries. If the min and max of the set of 5 numbers is 1 and 6, there's a gap in the numbers.

Another way to say this is for there to be a straight you need 5 distinct numbers, with the max - min == 4.

Comment: Is it possible to do a more in depth explanation, with the array I have?

Comment: @TylerK it's hard to be more in depth. Step through your array. At each step, put the number in a set, and test if the number is a new min or max. After the loop is done, check how many members the set has, is it equal to the length of the straight? And if it is, are the min and the max the right distance apart?